# Error Code : 1503: A Unique Index must include all columns in the table. How can I partition the table when a unique index is present?

Tags: mysql, partitioning

[image]

Column Definitions

The ID column is the primary key with auto-increment that we use to maintain the pool range.

Serial is unique and needs to be unique even after partitioning.

The status of a product is an enum with a value of A or U.

Problem:

I want to partition the table on the basis of status. Most SQL queries are based on a primary key or serial number with status A. When I am trying to create a partition using the query below, it is not working.

```
ALTER TABLE product
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(status)
(
   PARTITION used VALUES IN ('U'),
   PARTITION used VALUES IN ('A')
);
Error Code : 1503: A Unique Index must include all columns in the table
```

Can anyone tell me the right approach to solving this problem?

Comment: What is your goal in using partitioning? If your goal is to improve performance, partitioning is usually not necessary and no better than creating appropriate indexes.

Comment: I want to improve query performance as this table is huge.

Comment: "huge" -- Even a billion-row table is not necessarily helped by partitioning.  Show us the full table and some important queries.  We will help you formulate indexes to give you performance.  (Or we will explain how partitioning will help, but I doubt that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use ENUM - this datatype is not allowed in the partitioning expression. Use CHAR(1) with CHECK constraint instead. MySQL 8.0.16 or newer needed. If your version is lower then check this condition in the triggers.

You cannot define `serial` as UNIQUE with according index because any unique index must include all columns which are used in the partitioning expression. Use triggers instead.

Primary key must be composite - it must include both `status` column (see above) and `id` column as a prefix (needed for autoincrementing). If you need to check `id` uniqueness separately then expand the triggers codes accordingly.

### Sample

Create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE product (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `serial` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    status CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, status),
    CHECK (status IN ('A', 'U'))
);
```

Create triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr1
BEFORE INSERT ON product
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT NULL 
                FROM product 
                WHERE `serial` = NEW.`serial`
                ) THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The column ''serial'' must be unique.';
    END IF;
END
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr2
BEFORE UPDATE ON product
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                FROM product
                WHERE `serial` = NEW.`serial`
                  AND OLD.`serial` <> NEW.`serial`
                ) THEN 
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The column ''serial'' must be unique.';
    END IF;
END
```

Alter the table, create partitions:

```
ALTER TABLE product
PARTITION BY LIST COLUMNS(status)
(
   PARTITION used VALUES IN ('U'),
   PARTITION not_used VALUES IN ('A')
);
```

Insert legal rows:

```
INSERT INTO product (`serial`, status) VALUES ('ABC', 'A');
INSERT INTO product VALUES (DEFAULT, 'DEF', 'U', DEFAULT);
```

Insert duplicate by `serial` - error:

```
INSERT INTO product (`serial`, status) VALUES ('DEF', 'A');
```

> ```
> The column 'serial' must be unique.
> ```

Insert invalid `status` value - error:

```
INSERT INTO product (`serial`, status) VALUES ('GHI', 'X');
```

> ```
> Check constraint 'product_chk_1' is violated.
> ```

Update `serial` to existing value - error:

```
UPDATE product SET `serial` = 'ABC' WHERE `serial` = 'DEF';
```

> ```
> The column 'serial' must be unique.
> ```

Update with `serial` unchanged - allowed by the trigger:

```
UPDATE product SET created_at = NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY WHERE status = 'A';
```

See table content:

```
SELECT * FROM product;
```

| id | serial | status | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | DEF | U | 2023-12-21 06:07:14 |
| 1 | ABC | A | 2023-12-22 06:07:14 |

See single partition content:

```
SELECT * FROM product PARTITION (used);
```

| id | serial | status | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | DEF | U | 2023-12-21 06:07:14 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JWVtWNPE)

Comment: And the conclusion probably is not to use partitioning :)

Comment: @Akina
I was wondering if triggers are the only way to do this, however.
If I do not use indexes on serial, then the trigger will scan the complete table before inserting or updating.

I am thinking of creating a primary key out of id and status, then adding an index to serial and status, as it's my second query pattern. Additionally, it will increase the trigger performance.

Do you think it's adding value for query performance, or is it not the use case of partitioning?

Comment: @VirendraSinghRathore The index for a column which contains only 2 possible values won't be effective until one of these values is used in less than 5-7% of rows - does your dataset matches this condition? If not then follow Shadow's comment. *then adding an index to serial and status* Well, do it. My answer is a way, not a solution.

Comment: @VirendraSinghRathore we cannot tell you if partitioning helps with your queries as we do not know what queries you run. You want to partition by status field, so partitioning can only help with queries that use status for filtering, all other queries will be unaffected or perform worse. Not all queries referemcing status will benefit from partitioning. As Bill Karwin pointes out un his comment, partitioning is not great tool for performance. Well-defined indexes are simpler and more beneficial.

Comment: @Shadow
I run two types of queries
select from product where id > value limit 100
select from product where status = 'A' and serial in (serial list up to 3000) limit 3000

The primary key will serve my first kind of query, and the secondary index will serve my second query.

Comment: @VirendraSinghRathore then not sure why you want partitioning.

Comment: @shadow
Initially, these queries were working fine, but when the data increased in the table, queries became slower. Initially, I was selecting 15000 rows, and it was working, but I needed to reduce it to 3000. Most of my queries are on status A in conjunction with the serial number. That's why I thought about partitioning and fired my queries on the available partition. As its size will always be static, say a hundred thousand,.

Comment: @VirendraSinghRathore *Most of my queries are on status A in conjunction with the serial number.* The index by ```(status, `serial`)``` or ```(`serial`,status)``` seems to be enough (create both, check the plan for what of them is selected by the server, drop unused).

Answer (score 0):

If `serial` is unique and unlikely to ever change, then get rid of `id` and have a non-partitioned table with

```
PRIMARY KEY(serial)
```

(Please explain "maintain the pool range"; maybe `id` has some use.)

"want to partition the table on the basis of status".  Instead, consider using composite indexes such as

```
INDEX(status, serial)
INDEX(status, created_at)
```

With those, `WHERE status = 'U' ORDER BY created_at DESC` will run as fast or faster without partitioning.

And as mentioned by comments, this may be useful in some cases:

```
INDEX(serial, status)
```

"selecting 15000 rows" -- What does the client do with so many rows?  I would expect it to choke.

You have the date, what is the `id` for?

When walking through a large table, "remember where you left off".  This can be done even if the PK is composite.  Let's discuss further when I see the various queries you need.  (It may involve a composite `PRIMARY KEY` that is designed for performance of those large scans.)

More on "left off" in my blog pm [*Pagination*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

Comment: Yeah, I know you find the ID field strange, but I need this to tell how many serials are allocated to each supplier. I keep the min-max range in a different pool request table for each allocation request for compliance as well, and if two suppliers ask for serials at the same time, the supplier may end up with the same serials due to concurrency. I have a queue mechanism to solve this problem. I hope you understand why I am stuck with this ID field.

Comment: Intially, I was selecting 15000 serials using the in function, but it became slower, so I had to reduce it to 3000. Now the system is working fine with the reduced limit.

I have two query patterns.

1. I receive a list of large serial numbers from a CSV file that I need to validate and make sure are available.

2. If they are successfully validated, then I have to mark them as used.

3. Users can request available serials, and they should not be duplicated for any user.

Comment: @VirendraSinghRathore - I'm still somewhat lost.  Your example shows "ABC", but your discussion implies that maybe it is numbers 3000 through 5999.  In that case, I might suggest a second table that controls the doling out of batches of numbers to suppliers.  And gradually the supplier fills in up to 3000 rows in `product`.